# Generate source using jaxb from an xsd that is in my classpath

Tags: xsd, classpath, cxf, jaxb2, generated-code

I'm trying to generate java classes using JAXB from a schema in my class path.  For CXF I generated java classes from a wsdl in my classpath like so:

```
<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>classpath:wsdl/MetsInterfaceService.wsdl</wsdl>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

I was hoping something similar existed with JAXB.  I did try using a catalog but this seems to be more in line when a schema (stored in the same maven module) imports another schema in the classpath.

Any help would be appreciated!
-Sal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The [CXF XJC Maven Plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html) appears to support `classpath:`.**

> The XsdOption object is used to pass specific options and
>   configuration for each XSD file that is to be processed.

The example on the site shows `classpath:` used in several ways in `<xsdOption>` paths for `<xsd>`, `<bindingFile>`, and `<catalog>` paths:

```
<configuration>
    <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
    <xsdOptions>
        <xsdOption>
            <xsd>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/http.xsd</xsd>
            <bindingFile>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/http.xjb</bindingFile>
            <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/build-resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
        </xsdOption>
        <xsdOption>
            <xsd>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/ws-addr.xsd</xsd>
            <packagename>org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing</packagename>
        </xsdOption>
        <xsdOption>
            <xsd>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/addressing.xsd</xsd>
            <bindingFile>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/addressing.xjb</bindingFile>
        </xsdOption>
        <xsdOption>
            <xsd>classpath:/schemas/configuration/security.xsd</xsd>
            <bindingFile>classpath:/schemas/configuration/security.xjb</bindingFile>
            <catalog>${basedir}/src/main/build-resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
            <extensionArgs>
                <extensionArg>-Xdv</extensionArg>
            </extensionArgs>
        </xsdOption>
        <xsdOption>
            <xsd>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/ws-addr-wsdl.xsd</xsd>
            <bindingFile>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/ws-addr-wsdl.xjb</bindingFile>
            <extension>true</extension>
        </xsdOption>
        <xsdOption>
            <xsd>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/addressing200403.xsd</xsd>
            <bindingFile>classpath:/schemas/wsdl/addressing200403.xjb</bindingFile>
        </xsdOption>
    </xsdOptions>
</configuration>
```