# Generate a XSD from a JAXB-annotated class without using File

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to generate XSD from Java Annotated classes by following code mentioned in this post [Is it possible to generate a XSD from a JAXB-annotated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212064/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-xsd-from-a-jaxb-annotated-class)

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);

public class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

    public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(suggestedFileName);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
        return result;
    }

}
```

This technique is using File system, My requirement is to get the XML as String without using file system.

Is there any possibility the Implementation of `SchemaOutputResolver` may not write file to disk and return or set some instance variable with the String value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write the `StreamResult` on a `StringWriter` and get the string from that.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
MySchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
String schema = sor.getSchema();

public class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {
    private StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();    

    public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException  {
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
        result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
        return result;
    }

    public String getSchema() {
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, could please explain a bit, what you just did in `createOutput` function?